# How do I remove caulk from joints on a paneled door?

Tags: wood, hardwood-refinishing

I salvaged an old 4-panel wooden interior door and painstakingly stripped off much of the paint with the goal of re-finishing it with oil. It looks as though a previous owner filled in all the joints with caulk. The only method I've found to work remotely well in removing that is scraping while applying heat from a gun.
It's incredibly tedious, and very difficult to do without damaging the wood.

Am I overlooking something? Are my only options really repainting the door or finding a replacement?

Comment: Can you cut it with a utility knife.

Comment: Any sense of what type of caulk it is? Latex may respond to chemical paint strippers.

Comment: Spaces are too tight to cut without risking damage to the wood. 
No idea what the material is, but it's held up pretty well to the several applications of Citristrip needed to get the paint off.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not overlooking anything. Restoration of wood products, especially if the end goal is to put a clear (i.e. non-paint based) finish on, is a tedious, laborious, boring, painstaking process that can damage the wood if not done carefully.

But, it's usually worth it in the end.

Sounds like you've got a winner with your heat gun & scraper technique, just keep at it.

Comment: This would be a **Comment**, not a answer

Comment: @Ruskes  This is a decent answer.  One of the reasons the people who do it for others are not cheap, cost more than what I can pay.

Comment: @crip659 usually the answer is to provide a solution to the question,  I fail to see how this does that

Comment: The OP provided a solution, @Ruskes. This reinforces that what the OP is doing _is_ the best option (in my opinion, and that of at least 2 others who have up voted it). There are no simple, short-cut methods for doing wood restoration. Repainting/replacing are the other options, but they're not what the OP wants to do. It does now, though, answer the actual question asked, so thanks for pointing that out.